# nginx try_files confusion

Tags: nginx, redirect, directory

The setup I'm going for is as follows: I want nginx to look for a file in the /test subdirectory, and if it's not there, serve it from it's normal uri. I figured this would be fairly straightforward with try_files. Here's the setup I came up with:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  test-server;

    location / {
        root   /opt/www;
        index  index.php;
        try_files /test$uri $uri;
    }
}
```

This half-works. If I go to http://test-server/something, and there is a /test/something file, it will serve the /test/something file. However, if there isn't a /test/something file, but there is a /something file, it will return a 500 Internal Server error. My best guess is that there's some kind of recursive looping going on, but I don't know what the alternative would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last argument to try_files has to be a guaranteed file. $uri is not acceptable for this. Instead use `try_files /test$uri $uri =404;`